# Static variable pass by reference in Java

Tags: java, variables, global-variables, pass-by-reference

I have the following in class A:

```
static ArrayList<Student> students;
```

I have the following in class B:

```
public static void populate_students(ArrayList<Student> students) {
        students = new ArrayList<Student>();
// ...
}
```

in the debug mode, I see that `student` is initialized (not null) in the method but after returning to class A, student is null. Why is this the case? I thought that changes made on an object are visible from everywhere in Java.

Comment: "*I thought that changes made on an object are visible from everywhere in Java.*" yes, to object, not to reference.

Comment: Actually java is always pass by value and not pass by reference. The value of an object is then it's reference.

Answer (score 3):

If you pass the static `students` variable to the `populate_students`, the method can change the state of the instance referred by that variable, but it can't assign a new value to that variable. So if you pass `null` to the method, the static variable will remain `null` after the method returns.

Instead, you need to return the `List` from the method :

```
public static ArrayList<Student> populate_students() {
    ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
// ...
    return students;
}
```

And assign it to the static variable :

```
static ArrayList<Student> students = B.populate_students();
```

Answer (score 3):

Java is not pass-by-ref, it is pass-by-val (almost).

If you modify directly the `students` parameter without changing the reference, it modified value will be mutated to the original reference.

Exemple, `Collections.sort(students..)` will sort the list without having to catch it from a return.

However in your example, you re-assign a new list to `students` so your new `students` list in your method is not linked anymore to the old one.

I believe what you really want to do is

```
A.students = new ArrayList<Student>();
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no pass-by-reference in Java: primitives and references are passed by value. You cannot change a reference passed into your method by assigning it. If you saw `students` set to non-null value inside `populate_students`, it's because the debugger has figured out the new meaning of `students` from the context, and displayed the value of method's argument called `students` to you.

If you would like to produce a list in one method and set it into a variable inside a class, you can do it like this:

```
class A {
    static ArrayList<Student> students = B.populateStudents();
}
class B {
    public static ArrayList<Student> populateStudents() {
        ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
        ...
        return students;
    }
}
```